# strange character "â" in cmake generated makefile errors

Tags: c++, unix, cmake, gnu

Terrible title, sorry.  I used cmake to generate a makefile and I specified g++ as the C++ compiler and when I run the generated makefile using make or gmake I get all these compile errors and all my symbols have trailing â's on them.  Any thoughts on what might be behind these mysterious â's?

Comment: Do they appear in the source files or only in the compiler output? The former would indicate encoding issues, the latter might be something to do with C++ name mangling.

Comment: No, the â's do not appear in the source files, just the compiler output.

Answer (score 6):

You probably have the `LANG` environmental variable setup incorrectly. Try setting it to `C` or `en_US`.

If using `bash` something like `export LANG=C` or `export LANG=en_US` should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

They're Unicode quote marks, LEFT and RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK, which are encoded in UTF-8 as "\xE2\x80\x98" and "\xE2\x80\x99".  And '\xE2' in Latin-1 is 'â'.

So your choices are to figure out why your terminal is not interpreting UTF-8 correctly, or to tell g++ not to generate them.  The latter is done by setting `LANG=C` or so, as *the_void* noted, which will cause the compiler to emit ordinary ASCII quote marks instead.